# How to set angular (Select all ) in side the dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am trying to develop a dropdown in my Angular application. The Drop Down is shop list. When I select a shop it will show or (display) the content in the shop.so Here I want a new item  in shop list (item is ALL SHOP) inside the dropdown..Like
this

[image]
here the data(shopslists) are taking from Database(angular with web api)

This is my Ts code

```
 ngOnInit() {

            this.Service.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => this.outletDetails = outletsData,
                error => {


 console.error(error);
                this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
            });
    onSelect(shopid: number) {
    this.Service.FetchItemDetails(shopid, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
                        error => {
                            console.error(error);
                            this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
                        });
```

This is my HTML

```
  <span>
            <select class="formcontrol" name="outletDetail" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                <option value="0" disabled>Select a Shop</option>
                <option *ngFor="let outletDetail of outletDetails" value={{outletDetail.ShopID}}>{{outletDetail.ShopName}}</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Service.FetchPopulateOutlets().subscribe(outletsData => {
        let allShops = {
            ShopName: 'All',
            ShopID: 0
        }
        this.outletDetails = [allShops,...outletsData];
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
        this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
    });
    onSelect(shopid: number) {
        if (shopId == 0) {
            "Insert your logic here"
        }
        this.Service.FetchItemDetails(shopid, this.pageIndex).subscribe(itemsData => this.itemdetails = itemsData,
            error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.statusMessage = "Problem with the service.Please try again after sometime";
            });
    }
```

Comment: This only the idea how it shoud work, can you paste the errors you are getting. Maybe we can find a workable solution for you.

Comment: let allShops = {
 ShopName:'All',
 ShopID:'0'
}
this.outletDetails.push(allShops);
this.outletDetails.concat(outletsData)
wrap this part of the code in curly brackets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177092/discussion-between-akhil-and-irhad-ljubcic).